# Practice with l’imparfait

Tags: imparfait, ne-explétif

I’m practicing my usage of l’imparfait (as well as a few vocabulary words and phrases) by writing a blog entry about my childhood. I’d like to know if the following is grammatically correct, and makes sense to you as the reader:

> Pendant que je grandissais, ma mère aimait faire cuire - les biscuits étaient sa spécialité. Elle les faisait cuire durant les vacances, ou bien n’importe quand. Lorsque j’étais tout jeune, je m’amusais l’aider. Toutefois, je perdrais l’intérêt au fur et à mesure que passaient les années. Je m’asseyais à la table et lécher le glaçage du couteau plus que je n’aidais vraiment.

This is only an excerpt and I haven’t finished writing yet, but I want to make sure it flows well and sounds alright. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few improvements I may suggest you.

> Pendant **mon enfance**, ma mère aimait **cuisiner** (*ou faire la cuisine*) - les biscuits étaient sa spécialité. Elle les **confectionnait** **pendant** les vacances, ou bien à n’importe quel **autre** moment. Lorsque j’étais jeune (*ou enfant ou adolescent*), je m’amusais **à** l’aider. Toutefois, je **perdais de** l’intérêt au fur et à mesure que **les années** passaient. Je m’asseyais à la table et **léchais** le glaçage **sur le** couteau plus que je **ne l**'aidais vraiment.

Comment: Merci mille fois pour vos suggestions ! Il existe une différence entre « pendant » et « durant » ?

Comment: Dans cette phrase, pendant me semblait plus approprié même si les deux sont corrects.

Comment: @tssmith2425 "*que passaient les années*"' is not incorrect either. It's more literary but perfectly valid. Same with "*je n’aidais*" vs "*je ne l'aidais*", both are correct, it's not an actual mistake like "*je m’amusais l’aider*" for example.

Comment: I elected to use it in a more literary sense as I’m writing a piece of prose, so I’m glad it’s not incorrect. As far as “je ne l’aider,” I take it that the l’ is the neuter pronoun to fill in what would otherwise be ambiguous?